# preventing array of ticked checkboxes from being reprinted as unticked checkboxes

Tags: arrays, database, list, checkbox, echo

hella fellas, I got a little task about half done...this is regarding checkbox arrays in php code...

after i make a selection from a list of check boxes and I click submit, I get the check boxes that i ticked but i also get the entire list of check boxes printed again which is a problem because I do not want the check-boxes that I ticked to be displayed again, but they are displayed again but this time as an unchecked box.

I tried to use the array_diff method but I get warning signs instead telling me that my Argument is a string and not an array...so I'm really confused...i've uploaded the screenshots of the checkboxes to explain it better -

[IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/eqtmix.png[/IMG] - checkbox that i ticked

[IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/e5o16p.png[/IMG] - after i ticked the check box, as you can see, my selections are printed again - 
"Motor Binding And Connection", and "Repair Sensors" but this time they are unchecked.

when I use Array_diff I get the following error message:

Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\xampp1\htdocs\rajib1\rajib\php_checkbox1.php on line 50

here's my code without the array_diff method being used:

```
    <?php
include('dbcategory.php');
error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP: Get Values of Multiple Checked Checkboxes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/php_checkbox.css" />
</head>
<body>
<td valign="top">
 <?php

 $list = "SELECT * FROM skillsset WHERE category='Engineering' ORDER BY skills ASC";
$listAHI = $dbs ->prepare($list);
$listAHI -> execute();
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
while($row = $listAHI ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$skills = $row["skills"];
echo "
<form action='' method='post'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='skills[]' value='$skills'>  $skills<br> 

";

    }
    echo"<input type='submit' name='submit' Value='Submit'/></form>";
}

else {
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!empty($_POST['skills'])) {
foreach($_POST['skills'] as $skills1) {
echo "<p><form action='' method='post'><input type='checkbox' name='skills[]' value='$skills1' checked>".$skills1 ."</p>";
}

while($row = $listAHI ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$skills = $row["skills"];
//$result=array_diff($skills,$skills1);
//print_r($result);
echo "
<form action='' method='post'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='skills[]' value='$skills'>  $skills<br> 

";
}
}
}

else{
echo "<b>Please Select At least One Option.</b><input type='submit' name='submit' Value='Submit'/>";
}
}


?>
</td>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I add the following lines of code -     //$result=array_diff($skills,$skills1);
    //print_r($result);
which are commented, then I get the following error message:

Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\xampp1\htdocs\rajib1\rajib\php_checkbox1.php on line 50

here's the code for the table as well from which I retried the data to print out the listings with the checkboxes - please name the file skillsset.sql if you decide to copy and paste the code below and inject it into a mysql/apache (or any other) server - thnx

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.6
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Feb 04, 2015 at 04:01 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.16
-- PHP Version: 5.5.9

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `quietservices`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `skillsset`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skillsset` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `skills` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=40 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `skillsset`
--

INSERT INTO `skillsset` (`id`, `category`, `skills`) VALUES
(11, 'Information', 'PHP'),
(13, 'Information', 'C++'),
(14, 'Information', 'C#'),
(15, 'Information', 'Javascript'),
(17, 'Information', 'AJAX'),
(18, 'Information', 'Java'),
(19, 'Information', 'Adobe Photoshop'),
(21, 'Information', 'Adobe Premiere Pro'),
(22, 'Information', 'Final Cut'),
(28, 'Engineering', 'Power Factor Improvement (PFI)'),
(29, 'Engineering', 'Motor Binding & Connection'),
(31, 'Engineering', 'Transformer'),
(34, 'Engineering', 'AutoCAD'),
(35, 'Information', 'AutoCAD'),
(36, 'Engineering', 'Switchgear Panels'),
(37, 'Engineering', 'General Wiring'),
(38, 'Engineering', 'Repair Sensors'),
(39, 'Engineering', 'Install & Maintain Substation');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

please let me know how i can get the checked/ticked boxes from printing again as checked/ticked boxes when the complete list is retrieved and printed...thnx a mill!

Comment: I'm glad my answer worked, remember that you may vote up or mark it as accepted answer to help improve the user's reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement:

> I do not want the check-boxes that I ticked to be displayed again

You have **an array of the selected skills**, that you don't want to show again, and **another array with the entire list of skills** from the database.

So, when you are printing the list of skills again, before showing each item ask if that item is not present in the POSTed array. I would use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for this.

First **remove** this entire section because you are forcing the print of all POSTed items and **you don't want that**:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!empty($_POST['skills'])) {
foreach($_POST['skills'] as $skills1) {
echo "<p><form action='' method='post'><input type='checkbox' name='skills[]' value='$skills1' checked>".$skills1 ."</p>";
}
```

Then replace the immediately next while(...) with this:

```
echo "<form action='' method='post'>"; // You can use a single <form> item for all checkboxes
while($row = $listAHI ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // Traverse your entire list of skills.
    $skill = $row["skills"]; // I renamed your var to singular because this is a single skill item.
    if(isset($_POST['skills']) and !in_array($skill, $_POST['skills'])){
        // Skill not found on POSTed array; then show it.
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='skills[]' value='$skill'>$skill<br>";
    }
}
echo "</form>"; // close your form at end of checkboxes
```

I also noticed you are opening and closing a form for every checkbox you print, I assume you need them on a single form, so I modified your code to show a single form with all checkboxes.

I hope this fixes your problem.